# Booting Debian 10 "Buster" Only Without Display Manager Neither X Window System

Tags: debian, boot, boot-loader

Thinking if there is any way that Debian 10 "Buster" could be booted with its Kernel, `systemd`, all those packages, but without display manager neither X Window System, something like recovery mode, but more complete, with major part of `systemd` services.

How would that be done?

Reinstalling it or adjusting some GRUB file?

That way it would fall in command line interface, something like recovery mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot login to the system normally, you could use the boot option `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` to override the default of `graphical.target`.

If you can login to the system and have root access, you could use `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` to switch the system immediately to non-GUI mode, or `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` to set it as the default system state for any future boot-ups until told otherwise.

To switch back, use `systemctl isolate graphical.target` to start the GUI mode immediately, or `systemctl set-default graphical.target` to make it the default system state again.

The `multi-user.target` starts all network services, but omits the GUI subsystem. Many rack-mount servers run in that mode because they don't have any use for local GUI.

Comment: System is running normally, but my intention is to keep it running on lower use of CPU and RAM memory with some basic services. How can I apply this boot option?

Comment: As I said: run `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` and the non-GUI state will become the new default for all the future boot-ups. It has exactly the same effect as the boot option, but it will be stored persistently automatically. If you need to use the boot option, press <kbd>E</kbd> while in GRUB boot menu, and add `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` to the kernel line in the GRUB configuration; such boot-time edits will not be persistent, as GRUB's filesystem driver is read-only.

Comment: Read wrongfully, sorry.

Comment: @Vasconcelos1914 No problem.